# Average of the sum of N square numbers that itself is a perfect square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $n$ such that the average of $1^2+2^2+3^2 +...+n^2$  is a perfect square. I used the sum of squares formula then equated to $x^2$. What's next?

This is a BMO2 question but I can't find the question paper.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://nrich.maths.org/discus/messages/153904/BMO2_1994_Q1-146610.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I guess they assume you cannot find multiple solutions of a Pell equation by hand, which is a reasonable assumption.

However, the solutions of the Pell equation $x^2 - 48 y^2 = 1$ give everything. It turns out to be unnecessary to consider negative $x$ or $y,$ sometimes you get lucky that way. A pair $(x,y)$ is useful if we can solve $x = 4n+3,$ or $x \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ The first solution is $(7,1)$ because $49-48 = 1,$ and $x=7$ gives $n=1.$

Given $(x,y)$ with $x^2 - 48 y^2 = 1,$ the very next solution is
$$ ( 7x+48y, x+7y).  $$

So, in order,
$$ (7,1); \; \; n = 1.   $$
$$ (97,14); \; \; n = \mbox{not  integer}.   $$
$$ (1351,195); \; \; n = 337.   $$
$$ (18817,2716); \; \; n = \mbox{not  integer}.   $$
$$ (262087,37829); \; \; n = 65521.   $$
$$ (3650401, 526890); \; \; n = \mbox{not  integer}.   $$
$$ (50843527, 7338631); \; \; n = 12710881.   $$
$$ (708158977, 101213344 ); \; \; n = \mbox{not  integer}.   $$
$$ (9863382151, 1423656585); \; \; n = 2465845537.   $$
$$ (1.37 \cdot 10^{11}, 1.98 \cdot 10^{10} ); \; \; n = \mbox{not  integer}.   $$

The useful $x$ values, $7,1351,262087, 50843527,\ldots,$ let us call them $U_k,$ satisfy $$ U_{k+2} = 194 \, U_{k+1} - U_k.  $$

The associated  $n,$ values, $1,337,65521,12710881 , 2465845537 \ldots,$ call them $N_k,$
satisfy $$ N_{k+2} = 194 \, N_{k+1} - N_k+ 144.  $$